# Self-contained XSS

Tags: xss

is there a way to exploit the victims through Self-contained XSS, XSS vulnerabilities which are protected by CSRF protections based on login credential  ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that self-contained XSS is a `data:` URI containing HTML with JS, then no.

`data:` URIs are considered to have unique origin, which is different from all other origins.